# Adding Options to this Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am using Simple Lightbox (http://simplelightbox.com) and have it all working, however I am trying to some add options into the script however these are not working, what am I doing wrong?

```
<script>
    var lightbox = $('.gallery .col-md-6 .gallery-img a').simpleLightbox({
        captionPosition: top
    });
</script>
```

Comment: add quotes to `top`

Comment: Thanks that has resolved it, do you know how I can add a HTML caption? What is captionType and captionsData?

Comment: please read documentation, I saw quotes are missing, by going to your documentation link.